# Latex image miss location

Tags: graphics

When I use a figure command to insert an image , I notice that the image does not go where exactly I want , and even when I want it in a specific subsection I find it before that section

```
\begin{figure}

\label{fig:f43}
\caption{An Example }
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=6cm]{4-12}

\end{figure}
```

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD) for float placement possibilities, and [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](http://goo.gl/t01vUD) with regards to your incorrect use of `\label` *before* `\caption`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add where you want the figure to be (**h**ere, **t**op, **b**ottom). With an exclamation mark (**!**) you can force the figure to be where you want it to be, but this does not always work, because it sometimes would destroy the entire page layout

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=12cm, height=6cm]{4-12}
\caption{An Example }
\label{fig:f43}
\end{figure}
```

In addintion it should always be graphic, caption, label to avoid errors.